# Problems with variable changes in while loop

Tags: c, variables, while-loop, scanf

> My simple program is read from the text file one word at a time.

**example text file. (below)**

N 101001  Circular Queue            11          1

N 123456  List Linker               11          5

N 666666  Pseudocode Gen            38          3

N 110010  Stack Stretcher           3           2

**and simple codes including variables etc...**

```
char function;
    int number, init_stock, reorder;
    char info[100];

    FILE *fp;
    if((fp = fopen("input.txt", "r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("input open failed\n");
        return 0;
    }
    while(!feof(fp))
    {
        fscanf(fp, "%c %d %[A-z, ] %d %d ", &function, &number, info, &init_stock, &reorder);

    }
```

> When a variable was changed within the ' while loop',
>
> I expected  to affect it the next loop as well.

so.. first, 'Circular Queue' was stored in 'info'.

Second, when 'List Linker' was stored in 'info' because second string is shorter than first string,

I thought that the info array had string like this 'List Linkerue'.

> 1. info -- Circular Que**ue**
> 2. info -- List Linker+**ue**

**But the info seemed to be reset every time, and I do not know why.**

Comment: Did you try to debug?

Comment: @BarisYakut ah.. nope, I just wonder why it does not remain its value

Comment: So `info` contains “List Linker” after the second iteration?  Isn’t that what you want?

Comment: [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/1848654)

Comment: @dbush I expected the array to be uninitialized, so I tried to put one initialize code in the end of while loop. But I didn’t have to and I dont know why

Comment: Check the `scanf` manual to see whether `%[` automatically NUL-terminates the string (it probably does).

Comment: @melpomene Thank you for the link I’ll read it carefullly

Comment: You replaced the contents of the array with new contents.  Strings in C are null terminated, so nothing is printed after the null byte, even if the rest of the array contains values that were not overwritten.

Comment: behaviour of `%[A-z, ]` is implementation-defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the first pass the content of `info` is `"Circular Queue \0"` The `\0` at the end represents a single zero byte, it is the null character. This tells functions like `printf` where string ends.

Note that there is also a blank space at the end.

On the second pass the content of `info` is `"List Linker \0e"`. As you suspected, `fscanf` didn't fill the whole string. But it did add the null character, so you can't see the `e` at the end. Content of `info` will be

```
1st pass: "Circular Queue " ... followed by random bytes
2nd pass: "List Linker \0e "
```

You can also improve your function by changing the format to `%99[A-z, ]` because `info` is 100 bytes (including the null character) And make sure `fscanf` reads 5 values as expected. You might also consider changing the input so the values are separated by commas.

```
while(fscanf(fp, "%c %d %99[A-z, ] %d %d ", 
    &function, &number, info, &init_stock, &reorder) == 5)
{
    //optional: remove the extra space at the end of info
    int len = strlen(info);
    if(len)
        if(info[len - 1] == ' ')
            info[len - 1] = 0;
    printf("string: [%s] %d\n", info, number);
}
```